# if this linux commands applicable for android WIFI DIRECT?

Tags: android, linux, command, android-wifi, wifi-direct

i found resources talk about Wifi direct commands in linux at this [link](http://dishingtech.blogspot.com/2012/01/realtek-wi-fi-direct-programming-guide.html) .

i am wondered if these commands are applicable for android WIFI DIRECT ??? i need to access WIFI direct from terminal using rooted device.